# How do I store an input from console to a wchar_t variable?

Tags: c++, cin, wchar-t

I am creating a console program that will take in a directory from the user through the console and store it in a wchar_t variable.

For example, this could be a possible input from the user:

```
C:/Users/Skipher/Destop/test.txt
```

I found `std::wcin`and seemed to have written something to the wchar_t variable. However, when I try to print it out to the console again using `std::wcout`, it only prints out `C` out of the entire directory.

Am I writing incorrectly to the wchar_t variable? I saw that wchar_t variables hold values in the form of `L"some kind of string"`. How can I make sure that my value gets written properly?

```
std::string stringPath;
std::cin.ignore();
std::getline(std::cin, stringPath);
std::wstring wstrPath = std::wstring(stringPath.begin(), stringPath.end());
const wchar_t* wcharPath = wstrPath.c_str();
mFilePath = (pxcCHAR*)wcharPath;
```

During debugging, I see that wstrPath has the value I want: `L"C:/Users/Skipher/Destop/test.txt`
However, wcharPath has a value of `0xcccccccc <Error reading characters of string.>`

Lastly, I need to store the value to a `pxcCHAR*` variable `mFilePath` which is a typedef for wchar_t* as provided in an SDK. How can I do this long conversion from a `std::string` to `pxcCHAR*`?

Comment: A variable of type `wchar_t` can only hold a single character. You may be looking for `std::wstring`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the whole code or just the wcout (Try both, i'm not too sure which will work...) in a while loop. Somewhat like this :

```
    while (1 == 1)
{
    wchar_t someRandomVariable;
    wcout << "Input Directory: ";
    wcin >> someRandomVariable;
    wcout << "Directory: " << someRandomVariable;

}
```

Hopefully, it will work. It should print:

```
Input Directory: C:/Users/Skipher/Destop/test.txt
Directory: C:/Users/Skipher/Destop/test.txt
```